# When using Jquery append(), the div which is appending, isn't able to reach

Tags: jquery, input, append

i'm using the append function of Jquery to make a new input field each time the user clicks on a 'add' button. Together with the input field I want to put a div class 'remove', to the form.

So if the user clicks on the plus, the new inputfield has to show. and when he clicks in that input field on MIN, this field has to be removed.

http://jsfiddle.net/hg1zdc8p/1/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#plus2').click(function() {
    $("#link2").append('<p><input type="text" class="form-control extralink" name="websitepartner[]"><span id="plus2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus minus">MIN</span></p>');    
    });

    $('.minus').click(function() {
        $(this).parent('p').remove();
    });
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoud use .on() method to access appended element.It should work fine:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#plus2').click(function() {
    $("#link2").append('<p><input type="text" class="form-control extralink" name="websitepartner[]"><span id="plus2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus minus">MIN</span></p>');    
    });

    $(document).on('click','.minus',function() {
        $(this).parent('p').remove();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hg1zdc8p/2/

Answer (score 2):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

**As you are creating elements dynamically.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

General Syntax

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

In Your case

```
 $("#link2").on('click', '.minus', function () {
     $(this).parent('p').remove();
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/147n6b9v/)

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching an event to an element that isn't present during DOM initialisation. To attach events to dynamic elements, use this notation:

```
$("parent-element").on("click", "child-element", function(){});
```

Updated version of your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hg1zdc8p/4/